# Close tooltip should mention existing close reasons

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, tooltips

If you click close you can quickly determine what the current votes are (and you can cancel out).

However, I think a summary of the existing close reasons could be included in the tooltip, which currently just mentions how many more votes are needed.

Comment: I don't think that wouldn't add much value to something that already exists by clicking the `Close` button (and "you can quickly determine the current votes").

Comment: @Werner yeah, the existing tooltip isn't very useful either.

Comment: "Possible duplicate" already creates an automatic comment. Doesn't any additional info just bias your own opinion?

Comment: @Arjan Like I mention, you already get this information when you click, and if you never intended to actually vote, this reduces your chance of changing your mind.